# Extbase: How to prevent a Model from copying a ObjectStorage property?

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an ExtBase extension with a Model with a 1:n relation in it. E.G. so:

```
class School extends AbstractEntity {
    /**
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Pupil>
     * @copy ignore
     */
    protected $pupils = NULL;
}
```

If I clone a school in the Typo3 backend, all related pupils are also cloned. How can I prevent the model from cloning the related objects (it should leave empty the pupils object)? The @copy ignore annotations doesn't help.

Comment: The `@copy` annotation will only work in an extbase context, not in the backend - there the TCA is the controlling element. I can't tell you how to prevent copying in the backend, but the option [dontRemapTablesOnCopy](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Select/Index.html#columns-select-properties-dontremaptablesoncopy) could be the thing you need to use.

Comment: @Jost, sorry for the offtop, but where can I find a reference of all the annotations? I didn't know before today about _copy_...

Comment: @ViktorLivakivskyi, I don't know of a reference for the annotations, sorry.

Comment: Patrick Lobacher made a CheatSheet which lists the annotations, http://www.lobacher.de/files/cs/ExtbaseFluidCheatSheet_3.02_pluswerk.pdf
But it did not tell anything about `@copy`. Looks like this is not a part of Extbase, is it?

Comment: @Jost I already tried it. It doesn't work. And it works only for the field type select, it doesn't work for inline elements.

Comment: @JayDinse you are right. I already found tons of docs, but nothing what really helps. The copy seems to be a part of third party cloning plugins.

Comment: @iMx In my opinion it is a good behavior that all nested models will be cloned by default when cloning an object. It still doesn't mean that it will be immediately persisted this way. Therefore I would suggest to set the ObjectStorage `$pupils` of your cloned model to an empty ObjectStorage before persisting the model. Doesn't that fit to your needs?

Comment: @JayDinse There are two places where an object may be cloned: In the frontend when using extbase (that is where one can do what you suggest, or use a cloning service which does this using annotations), or in the backend, where you can't really influence the process, except by configuration.

Comment: @JayDinse Jost is right. It happens in the backend, so I can't set anything. Now I decoupled the pupils from the School object and request them with an additional request.